# Echarts pie drag recalulate not work echarts new version

Tags: echarts

I can not use the new version (3.x / 4.x) of the drag calculation feature that I use Echarts 2.x pie chart. Does the new version support this feature? Does the calculable option work on newer versions? If you are supportive, I can rejoice if you can help me to do what I need to do.

```
var option = {
        title: {
            text: result.Baslik,
            subtext: result.AltBaslik,
            x: 'center'
        },
        toolbox: {
            show: true,
            feature: {
                magicType: {
                    show: true,
                    type: ['pie']
                },
                restore: {
                    show: true
                },
                saveAsImage: {
                    show: true
                }

            }
        },
        calculable: true,
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item',
            formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} " + result.BirimAdi + " ({d}%)"
        },
        legend: {
            orient: 'vertical',
            x: 'left',
            data: (function () {
                var res = [];
                var len = result.Veri.length;
                for (var i = 0, size = len; i < size; i++) {
                    res.push({
                        name: result.Veri[i].Ad
                    });
                }
                return res;
            })()
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Grafik',
                type: 'pie',
                radius: '55%',
                center: ['50%', '60%'],
                data: (function () {
                    var res = [];
                    var len = result.Veri.length;
                    for (var i = 0, size = len; i < size; i++) {
                        res.push({
                            name: result.Veri[i].Ad,
                            value: result.Veri[i].Deger
                        });
                    }
                    return res;
                })(),
                itemStyle: {
                    emphasis: {
                        shadowBlur: 10,
                        shadowOffsetX: 0,
                        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the current Echart Documentation "Calculable" only available for "Visual Map" not for PIE chart.

But I think we can integrate with the pie chart.

[image]